# hide extjs menu when clicking in different iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, extjs, extjs3

I have the following problem:
I have an extjs menu in one iframe, and when i click outside this iframe the menu does not collapse, like it does when I click away in the same iframe the menu belongs to.

Do you guys have an idea on how to solve this issue? 
This actually happens to any component that should hide when it loses focus. So, I'd love to see a more general solution, if you guys happen to know.

Thanks!

P.S.: I'm using version 3.2

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know if your parent frame is also running a ExtJS application, you are likely going to need to utilize XDM (cross-domain messaging). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage

You would then need to add a listener on the parent frame for clicks within the window, and pass that click event to the iframe. The iframe would then handle the click as needed, which in your case is dismissing the menu.

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work for me. The solution needs to be compatible to a great range of IE version.

Comment: Are you supporting anything past IE8? (IE6/IE7, etc)

Comment: You can check out easyXDM which handles many of those browser compatibility issues for you: http://easyxdm.net/.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for a solution on this one.

You can address the Extjs menu and hide all open menus from the parent frame like this (fe inside a click event on the parent):

```
var menu = window.frames[0].[ExtApplicationName].app.getController('[CONTROLLER]').getMenu().items.items
```

Next, you can loop through the menu items and hide them by doing:

```
menu[i].menu.hide();
```